# Create list with value from different dynamic sheets

Tags: list, google-sheets, filter, whitespace, trim

I have a list of values in three different sheets that are dynamic in column A, I have to put merge the three of them into a main sheet big list.

In the image the color squares are the different sheets and in the right is the merge sheet where I need this merged list with the values from all the other sheets something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER({'Sheet 5'!A:A; 'Sheet 6'!A:A; 'Sheet 7'!A:A}; 
        {'Sheet 5'!A:A; 'Sheet 6'!A:A; 'Sheet 7'!A:A}<>"")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that.

```
=QUERY(C:C,"select * where C is not null")
```

You can use `FILTER()` function like

```
=FILTER(C:C,C:C<>"")
```

Comment: Hi I didn't understand how to use the query formula but I tried with the Filter and it didn't work I used like this : `=FILTER('Sheet 5'!A:A,'Sheet 6'!A:A,'Sheet 7'!A:A, <>"")`

Comment: Share a sample workbook. You can't refer multiple sheet in this way.

Comment: You may try `=QUERY({'Sheet 5'!A:A;'Sheet 6'!A:A;'Sheet 7'!A:A},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null")` for multiple sheet.

Comment: I'm still not understand what it means this: `"select Col1 where Col1 is not null")`  I'm not really sure what I need to do there. Also I updated the publication with a better image to explain it. Also one of the comments below put this formula `=FILTER({'Sheet 5'!A:A; 'Sheet 6'!A:A; 'Sheet 7'!A:A}; 
        {'Sheet 5'!A:A; 'Sheet 6'!A:A; 'Sheet 7'!A:A}<>"")` and this gives me what I need.

Comment: Did you try my formula? What result do you get?

Comment: Yeah I tried it but it gives me this error: `Error of formula analysis.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:A;Sheet2!A2:A;Sheet3!A1:A},"where Col1 is not null")
```

or

```
=query({Sheet1!A1:A;Sheet2!A2:A;Sheet3!A1:A};"where Col1 is not null")
```

according to your locale